# Implementing a Drop Down Menu with a Country List into a JavaForm

Tags: java, user-interface, drop-down-menu, country, jform

So, I was wondering how I would go about implementing a list of all the countries in the world, into my JavaForm.

As I don't want to sit and write out all the countries in the world, I would like to implement a outside list, but I can't find anywhere where I can actually find out how to implement a drop down list like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdaEk.jpg

I came here therefore looking for some help. This is what my current GUI looks like, and then I would like a drop down menu to be beneath the country panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this [class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Getalistofcountrynames.htm) and retrieve all the countries in the world. I also recommend you to use a [auto suggestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801951/text-field-with-autosuggest) in the country textfield.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got a lot of different results whenever I searched google, and couldn't find this. :)

Comment: I would give you a point, but I dont have enough myself :D I checked yours off as an answer though.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks.